# Iterating date for common sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have a query. That is repeative.  Essentially, I'm gathering monthly data for 13 months.

The common query is essentially this:

```
    SELECT
        SUM(Timecards.Work_Amt_USD) AS billableDollars,
        SUM(Timecards.Work_Hours) AS billableHours,
        Entities.Timekeeper_Id AS Timekeeper_Id
    FROM dim.Elmts_Ent_Entity AS Entities
    INNER JOIN fact.Rec_Work_Timecard AS Timecards
        ON Entities.id = Timecards.Working_Timekeeper_Id
    WHERE Date_Worked_Effective >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
        AND Date_Worked_Effective < DATEADD(MONTH, -1 + 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
        AND (Work_Amt_USD <> 0
        OR Work_Hours <> 0)
    GROUP BY Timekeeper_Id, Date_Worked_Effective
```

The only thing that changes is the dates:

```
WHERE Date_Worked_Effective >= DATEADD(MONTH, ***CHANGE HERE -1***, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
        AND Date_Worked_Effective < DATEADD(MONTH, ****CHANGE HERE -1*** + 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
```

This will subtract the months for a set of months [-1 to -13].

Currently, this sql is copied 13 times.  I'd like to iterated 13 times instead.

I looked at common table expressions, but it wasn't clear how to pass the month variable.  Is the best way to do this just to make a stored procedure or function?

Upon which I would call:

```
GetMonthSummary(-1)
GetMonthSummary(-2)
GetMonthSummary(-3)
...
```

Full messy query here: 
[query](http://dpaste.com/2598YSJ)

Comment: Personally I would just make it a stored procedure and pass in the start date and end date values.

Comment: Ok, I guess I just want to iterate months 0-13 programmatically.  That's the root of the problem.  Looking for a "foreach" like solution to run the query and join it after 13 times.

Comment: StartDate and EndDate is a good idea, you can transfer -1, -2, -3 to startdate and enddate in stored procedure and make your stored procedure easy to read.

Comment: You could do the iteration in your stored procedure with a cursor, then Union your results into one table and return it, or create a temp table and insert records into it by month in your cursor loop.

Comment: Just added a the query for better understanding.  Could use a cursor, I supposed. Thanks

Comment: Glancing at your attempting query it appears you wanted to appeand the monthly results in the horizontal direction anyway. My answer below might be irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for you help though! @shawnt00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would I be right that the following produces basically what you need in row form?

```
WITH time_data AS
(
    SELECT
        Entities.Timekeeper_Id
        ,Timecards.Work_Amt_USD
        ,Timecards.Work_Hours
        ,DATEDIFF(YEAR, Date_Worked_Effective, GETDATE()) AS years_prior
        ,DATEDIFF(MONTH, Date_Worked_Effective, GETDATE()) AS months_prior

    FROM 
        dim.Elmts_Ent_Entity AS Entities

    INNER JOIN 
        fact.Rec_Work_Timecard AS Timecards
        ON (Entities.id = Timecards.Working_Timekeeper_Id)
)
SELECT
    Timekeeper_Id
    ,months_prior
    ,SUM(Work_Amt_USD) AS billable_dollars
    ,SUM(Work_Hours) AS billable_hours

FROM
    time_data

GROUP BY 
    Timekeeper_Id, years_prior, months_prior

ORDER BY
    Timekeeper_Id, years_prior, months_prior
```

If you then need to translate the summary for each month into columns going across, filter for (e.g.) `months_prior BETWEEN 1 AND 12`, and then use the `PIVOT` facility.

Certainly, the full query you linked to is a dog's dinner!

**EDIT:** From comments below.

This should give you an idea of how to pivot the results and assemble them all together. Since it's repetitive work, I'll leave you to interleave the columns into the final form you may prefer!

And again, I'm writing this off the cuff without testing.

```
WITH time_data AS
(
    SELECT
        Entities.Timekeeper_Id
        ,ISNULL(Timecards.Work_Amt_USD, 0) AS Work_Amt_USD
        ,ISNULL(Timecards.Work_Hours, 0) AS Work_Hours
        ,DATEDIFF(YEAR, Date_Worked_Effective, GETDATE()) AS years_prior
        ,DATEDIFF(MONTH, Date_Worked_Effective, GETDATE()) AS months_prior

    FROM 
        dim.Elmts_Ent_Entity AS Entities

    INNER JOIN 
        fact.Rec_Work_Timecard AS Timecards
        ON (Entities.id = Timecards.Working_Timekeeper_Id)
)

,timekeeper_ids AS
(
    SELECT Timekeeper_Id 
    FROM time_data 
    GROUP BY Timekeeper_Id
)

,monthly_data_source AS
(
    SELECT
        Timekeeper_Id
        ,months_prior
        ,SUM(Work_Amt_USD) AS billable_dollars
        ,SUM(Work_Hours) AS billable_hours
    FROM time_data
    WHERE months_prior BETWEEN 1 AND 13
    GROUP BY Timekeeper_Id, months_prior
)
,yearly_data_source AS
(
    SELECT
        Timekeeper_Id
        ,years_prior
        ,SUM(Work_Amt_USD) AS billable_dollars
        ,SUM(Work_Hours) AS billable_hours
    FROM time_data
    WHERE years_prior BETWEEN 0 AND 4
    GROUP BY Timekeeper_Id, years_prior
)
,rolling_twelve_data_source AS
(
    SELECT
        Timekeeper_Id
        --,(months_prior / 12) AS rolling_twelve_prior
        ,SUM(Work_Amt_USD) AS billable_dollars
        ,SUM(Work_Hours) AS billable_hours
    FROM time_data
    WHERE (months_prior / 12) = 0 --the last 12 months
    GROUP BY Timekeeper_Id --, (months_prior / 12)
)   

,pivoted_monthly_dollars AS
(
    SELECT 
         Timekeeper_Id
        ,[1] AS m01_dollars
        ,[2] AS m02_dollars
        ,[3] AS m03_dollars
        ,[4] AS m04_dollars
        ,[5] AS m05_dollars
        ,[6] AS m06_dollars
        ,[7] AS m07_dollars
        ,[8] AS m08_dollars
        ,[9] AS m09_dollars
        ,[10] AS m10_dollars
        ,[11] AS m11_dollars
        ,[12] AS m12_dollars
        ,[13] AS m13_dollars
    FROM (SELECT Timekeeper_Id, months_prior, billable_dollars FROM monthly_data_source) AS mds
    PIVOT (
        MAX(billable_dollars)
        FOR months_prior IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13])
    ) AS pivot_result
)
,pivoted_monthly_hours AS
(
    SELECT
         Timekeeper_Id
        ,[1] AS m01_hours
        ,[2] AS m02_hours
        ,[3] AS m03_hours
        ,[4] AS m04_hours
        ,[5] AS m05_hours
        ,[6] AS m06_hours
        ,[7] AS m07_hours
        ,[8] AS m08_hours
        ,[9] AS m09_hours
        ,[10] AS m10_hours
        ,[11] AS m11_hours
        ,[12] AS m12_hours
        ,[13] AS m13_hours
    FROM (SELECT Timekeeper_Id, months_prior, billable_hours FROM monthly_data_source) AS mds
    PIVOT (
        MAX(billable_hours)
        FOR months_prior IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13])
    ) AS pivot_result
)

,pivoted_yearly_dollars AS
(
    SELECT
         Timekeeper_Id
        ,[0] AS y00_dollars
        ,[1] AS y01_dollars
        ,[2] AS y02_dollars
        ,[3] AS y03_dollars
        ,[4] AS y04_dollars
    FROM (SELECT Timekeeper_Id, years_prior, billable_dollars FROM yearly_data_source) AS yds
    PIVOT (
        MAX(billable_dollars)
        FOR years_prior IN ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4])
    ) AS pivot_result
)
,pivoted_yearly_hours AS
(
    SELECT 
         Timekeeper_Id
        ,[0] AS y00_hours
        ,[1] AS y01_hours
        ,[2] AS y02_hours
        ,[3] AS y03_hours
        ,[4] AS y04_hours
    FROM (SELECT Timekeeper_Id, years_prior, billable_hours FROM yearly_data_source) AS yds
    PIVOT (
        MAX(billable_hours)
        FOR years_prior IN ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4])
    ) AS pivot_result
)

SELECT
    tids.Timekeeper_Id
    ,pmd.*
    ,pmh.*
    ,pyd.*
    ,pyh.*
    ,rtds.billable_dollars AS rtds_billable_dollars
    ,rtds.billable_hours AS rtds_billable_hours

FROM
    timekeeper_ids AS tids

LEFT JOIN
    pivoted_monthly_dollars AS pmd
    ON (pmd.Timekeeper_Id = tids.Timekeeper_Id)

LEFT JOIN
    pivoted_monthly_hours AS pmh
    ON (pmh.Timekeeper_Id = tids.Timekeeper_Id)

LEFT JOIN
    pivoted_yearly_dollars AS pyd
    ON (pyd.Timekeeper_Id = tids.Timekeeper_Id)

LEFT JOIN
    pivoted_yearly_hours AS pyh
    ON (pyh.Timekeeper_Id = tids.Timekeeper_Id)

LEFT JOIN
    rolling_twelve_data_source AS rtds
    ON (rtds.Timekeeper_Id = tids.Timekeeper_Id)

ORDER BY
    tids.Timekeeper_Id
```

Comment: Yes. This is close. And yes,I would need to use `PIVOT`. But, yeah that original query is brutal.

Comment: @user1093111, that's good. I've included an edit to show how to pivot and assemble it all together.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Getting and error `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 66
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.`.  Could be related to SQL type (T-SQL). It doesn't like the alias in the "IN"

Comment: @user1093111, I'm getting confused where I've put the column aliases. Instead of `[1] AS m01_dollars`, you need to remove the column alias from that part of the pivot (leaving just the `[1]` in place), and put it into the select statement like so `SELECT [1] AS m01_dollars ...`(instead of `SELECT *`). Do that for every column.

Comment: Yup, looked it up as well. 
Thanks, that fixed it

Comment: @user1093111, I've edited my answer further to reflect. This must be what programming was like old-school - doing it all by hand in a text editor without immediate access to a debugger haha!

Comment: I must say, I was thoroughly impressed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164710/discussion-between-user1093111-and-steve).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple loop in TSQL that while run from an interactive window like SSMS. Not sure if you really need a single result set or if you might need a parameterized query instead that's usable from within another app.

```
@DECLARE @N INTEGER = 1;

WHILE @N <= 13
BEGIN
    SELECT
        SUM(Timecards.Work_Amt_USD) AS billableDollars,
        SUM(Timecards.Work_Hours) AS billableHours,
        Entities.Timekeeper_Id AS Timekeeper_Id
    FROM dim.Elmts_Ent_Entity AS Entities
    INNER JOIN fact.Rec_Work_Timecard AS Timecards
        ON Entities.id = Timecards.Working_Timekeeper_Id
    WHERE Date_Worked_Effective >= DATEADD(MONTH, -@N, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
        AND Date_Worked_Effective < DATEADD(MONTH, -@N + 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
        AND (Work_Amt_USD <> 0 OR Work_Hours <> 0)
    GROUP BY Timekeeper_Id, Date_Worked_Effective;
    SET @N = @N + 1;
END
```

For a single resultset you can do something like this:

```
with mnths as (
    select offset from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13)) n(offset)
)
select q.*
from mnths cross apply (
    SELECT
        SUM(Timecards.Work_Amt_USD) AS billableDollars,
        SUM(Timecards.Work_Hours) AS billableHours,
        Entities.Timekeeper_Id AS Timekeeper_Id
    FROM dim.Elmts_Ent_Entity AS Entities
    INNER JOIN fact.Rec_Work_Timecard AS Timecards
        ON Entities.id = Timecards.Working_Timekeeper_Id
    WHERE Date_Worked_Effective >= DATEADD(MONTH, -mnths.offset, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
        AND Date_Worked_Effective < DATEADD(MONTH, -mnths.offset + 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
        AND (Work_Amt_USD <> 0 OR Work_Hours <> 0)
    GROUP BY Timekeeper_Id, Date_Worked_Effective
) q;
```

One obvious advantage here is that you can pretty much drop the query in as is. Because the query is "modularized" you don't have to worry about reasoning through the joins and group logic to make sure you're concatenating all the results together.

Comment: Ok, so just cross apply it to join the results.  Noted

Comment: There is no reason to be using `CROSS APPLY`.  Unless I am missing something the results will be exactly the same as in the solution I provided, except slower since the right part will have to be evaluated for each row on the left.

Comment: Don't you find that cross joins usually open you up to big performance problems?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to have one result set, then you can use a CTE to create a set of indexes, and join to them in the main query.  You could either provide a list of values to the Indexes, or you could use a recursive CTE to generate a variable lit.

To ensure you get the same rows you would've if you had distinct queries, add the Index value to the `Group By`.  This might not be entirely necessary, as I can't imagine a quirk where the same Effective Date would appear in with different indexes.

```
DECLARE @IndexCount INT = 13;

WITH indexes AS (
  SELECT -1 [IndexValue]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT [IndexValue] - 1
  FROM indexes
  WHERE IndexValue * -1 <= @IndexCount
)
SELECT
  SUM(Timecards.Work_Amt_USD) AS billableDollars,
  SUM(Timecards.Work_Hours) AS billableHours,
  Entities.Timekeeper_Id AS Timekeeper_Id
FROM dim.Elmts_Ent_Entity AS Entities
CROSS JOIN indexes 
INNER JOIN fact.Rec_Work_Timecard AS Timecards
  ON Entities.id = Timecards.Working_Timekeeper_Id
WHERE Date_Worked_Effective >= DATEADD(MONTH, indexes.IndexValue, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
  AND Date_Worked_Effective < DATEADD(MONTH, indexes.IndexValue + 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
  AND (Work_Amt_USD <> 0 OR Work_Hours <> 0)
GROUP BY Timekeeper_Id, Date_Worked_Effective, indexes.IndexValue
```

Comment: That might work for this particular query but it wouldn't be a good general approach.

Comment: Yeah, I was hung up on the indexes.  The CTE would draw from a result set, and I wasn't sure how get that to be the indexes.  What's a general approach you'd recommend?

Comment: @user1093111 I'm not getting what's missing in the solution here?  Are you saying you want to parameterize the count of indexes - that it could be 1 or 100, not just 13?

Comment: I think it would work, but you had said "it wouldn't be a good general approach"

Comment: That was shawnt00's opinion.  IMO - This will perform a lot better than his solution.  `CROSS APPLY` is a real dog when it comes to performance - it's like creating a table valued function and running it once for each row on the left.

Comment: We clearly can only guess at performance issues at this point. The problem with this is going to be once you start using outer joins or have conditions where the data does overlap.

Comment: @shwant00 - They will never overlap if you add IndexValue to the `GROUP BY`.  And as the query is now, I don't think that's even necessary.

Comment: I don't disagree that is should work. But if we're modifying the query they we'd just widen the whole range and cover everything without the cross join at the same time. At that point you're not really parameterizing/iterating the query. We really have no idea how this query is intended to be used.